# VBA Word: Applying Character Style to first two words of specific paragraph style

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to apply a character style ("Bold Italics") to the first two words of all paragraphs set in the "3 Species" style in MS Word (and later, I'd also like another macro to do same for all the words after the second tab in a different style). I know how to do all this in InDesign, but I'd like it set up in the original Word documents before they get flowed into InDesign.

I'm new at this and can't figure out how to apply it to only the first two words. I did get it to apply the character style to the whole paragraph or to a specific word in that style. It seems like it ought to be simple, but I've only learned to use find and replace type functions so far, and I imagine I will have to use the Range functions, which I don't understand yet. Thanks for any help!

```
Sub Add_Character_Style()
'
' Add_Character_Style Macro
'
  Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Style = "3 Species"
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Replacement.Style = "Bold Italics"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
   End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "<*>[,. ^s^t]@<*>"
    .Style = "3 Species"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Format = True
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    .Style = "Bold Italics"
    .Start = .Paragraphs(1).Range.End
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Macropod. It works beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Sub Add_Character_Style()
    Dim p As Paragraph
    Dim doc As Document: Set doc = ActiveDocument
    For Each p In doc.Paragraphs
        p.Range.Select
        Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
        With Selection
            If .Style = "3 Species" Then .Style = "Bold Italic"
        End With
    Next p
End Sub
```

EDIT:
To avoid use of the `Selection` object (Timothy Rylatt)

```
Sub Add_Character_Style()
   Dim p As Paragraph
   Dim doc As Document: Set doc = ActiveDocument
   Dim rng As Range
   For Each p In doc.Paragraphs
      If p.Range.Style = "3 Species" Then
         Set rng = p.Range
         With rng
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
            .MoveEnd Unit:=wdWord, Count:=2
            .Style = "Bold Italics"
         End With
      End If
   Next p
End Sub
```

FURTHER EDIT per macropod:

```
Sub Add_Character_Style()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Para As Paragraph, Rng As Range
For Each Para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
  With Para
    If .Style = "3 Species" Then
      If .Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords) > 1 Then
        Set Rng = .Range.Words.First
        With Rng
          Do While .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords) < 2
            .MoveEnd wdWord, 1
          Loop
          .Style = "Bold Italic"
        End With
      End If
    End If
  End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Working with Selections is neither necessary nor efficient.

Comment: Whilst I’m sure your code would work it would be horribly inefficient. Testing the style of the paragraph before selecting it would be more logical, and be a small improvement. But, as macropod said, it is rarely necessary to use the `Selection` object in VBA.

Comment: @macropod + @Timothy Many thanks. Would either of you mind to edit my answer adding code (below mine) to transform my code so that no `Selection` is used **keeping the logic if possible**. I always had the impression that in word vba (unlike excel vba) it is a common pattern to use `Selection`s. *This is NOT a challenge*, I genuinely want to know how.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Testing the paragraph for style assumes that the first 2 words have the same style as the paragraph. However, since the OP is changing the style of part of a paragraph, it was possible (in my mind) that the styles were different to start with.

Comment: In Word VBA you avoid use of `Selection` for exactly the same reasons as in Excel. I have edited your answer to show how it could be done with your code. The better approach, however, is to use `Find` as the OP did.

Comment: The problem with '.MoveEnd Unit:=wdWord, Count:=2' is that this will treat punctuation characters as words in their own right. Accordingly, after 'With Rng' you really need something like 'Do While .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords) < 2: .MoveEnd wdWord, 1: Loop'. You also need to test whether the paragraph actually has two or more words... Turning off screen updating also helps the code run faster. See my further edits

Comment: The code in my answer will still be faster, though.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick help! Hopefully studying the working code will help me understand better how Visual Basic works. My main job is as a graphic designer and layout person, but I need to speed up the editing process for people doing the editing as well.